# Unresolved name `thread::scoped` in an elementary program

Tags: rust

Why do I get a compilation failure in this elementary program?

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    for i in 1..10 {
        let _ = thread::scoped( move || {
            println!("hello from thread {}", i);
        });
    }
}
```

I try to build the program and I get:

```
src/main.rs:5:17: 5:36 error: unresolved name `thread::scoped`
src/main.rs:5         let _ = thread::scoped( move || {
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why?

The version of Rust I use:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (170c4399e 2015-01-14 00:41:55 +0000)
```

Comment: Which version of rustc are you using?

Comment: @Dogbert: 1.0.0-nightly (2015-01-14)

Comment: @IgorChubin, that is now more than 2 months old, and the APIs have changed in the mean time (the docs on doc.rust-lang.org are for the lastest nightly).

Comment: @huon-dbaupp: That's right! After update all works like a charm!! Thank you huon-dbaupp and Dogbert

Answer (score 2):

The problem indeed was with the version of the rustc.
After upgrade the program was successfully compiled:

```
   Compiling examples v0.0.1 (file:///home/igor/rust/projects/examples)
src/main.rs:1:5: 1:16 warning: unused import, #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default
src/main.rs:1 use std::thread;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

The warning disappeared after I removed *use*:

```
fn main() {
    for i in 1..10 {
        let _ = thread::scoped( move || {
            println!("hello from thread {}", i);
        });
    }
}
```

(Thank you, *huon-dbaupp* and *Dogbert*, for your help).